# R - transform quotient by the divisor to a summation

Tags: r

There is a list of weighted values. Integers in a second list are used for the weighting. The values are divided by the integers.

I am struggling with (also because I do not know the correct mathematical term or function term in `r`) the transformation of the resulting quotients.
These should be transformed, so a summation of the quotient appears, which is determined by the divisor/specific integer.

```
values <- c(100, 101, 102, 103, 316, 330, 106, 205)
> values
[1] 100 101 102 103 316 330 106 205

vectors <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2)
> vectors
[1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 2
```

The correct result of a division of the values by the integers is indeed:

```
> values/vectors
[1] 100.0000 101.0000 102.0000 103.0000 105.3333 110.0000 106.0000 102.5000
```

However, I would like to transform the result by taking the integers into account, so that in the end the following result would appear:

```
[1] 100.0000 101.0000 102.0000 103.0000 105.3333 105.3333 105.3333 110.0000 110.0000 110.0000 106.0000 102.5000 102.5000
```

Thank you.

Comment: It‘s not clear to me what you want, e.g. the 5th value of 316/3. how does that end up to be 103? Can you explain?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion! I corrected the desired output.

Comment: In that case, tivd‘s answer is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `rep()` function:

```
values <- c(100, 101, 102, 103, 316, 330, 106, 205)
vectors <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2)

> rep(values / vectors, times = vectors)
 [1] 100.0000 101.0000 102.0000 103.0000 105.3333 105.3333 105.3333 110.0000 110.0000 110.0000
[11] 106.0000 102.5000 102.5000
```